# What happens when we turn mobile Horizontal to Vertical?

Tags: android, orientation

What happens when we change orientation from Horizontal to Vertical or visa versa in Android Device?
Exactly,what happens in background?
i have curiosity to know what happens in back there?

Comment: The Activity is restarted

Comment: Activity View is re inflated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In API level 13 or above, the screen size changes when the orientation changes, so this still causes the activity to be destroyed and started when orientation changes.

If you don't want to change anything while happening this you need to do like:

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivityName"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
</activity>
```

in your manifest file.

Now, when your change orientation (and screen size changes), the activity keeps its state and onConfigurationChanged() is called. This will keep whatever is on the screen (ie: webpage in a Webview) when the orientation changes.

Learned this from this site:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

and refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) for run time changes